# LINQ: Include clause is causing two left join when there should be one

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am using below LINQ query:

```
    CreateObjectSet<ClientCustomFieldValue>()
.Include(scf => scf.ClientCustomField.CustomField)
.Where(str => str.PassengerTripID == passengerTripID).ToList();
```

Sql corresponding to this query  is(as per sql profiler)

exec sp_executesql

```
N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ClientCustomFieldValueID] AS [ClientCustomFieldValueID], 
    [Extent1].[ClientCustomFieldID] AS [ClientCustomFieldID], 
    [Extent1].[PassengerTripID] AS [PassengerTripID], 
    [Extent1].[DataValue] AS [DataValue], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Extent1].[LastChangeSecSessionID] AS [LastChangeSecSessionID], 
    [Extent1].[LastChangeTimeUTC] AS [LastChangeTimeUTC], 
    [Extent2].[ClientCustomFieldID] AS [ClientCustomFieldID1], 
    [Extent2].[ClientID] AS [ClientID], 
    [Extent2].[CustomFieldID] AS [CustomFieldID], 
    [Extent2].[CustomFieldSourceEnumID] AS [CustomFieldSourceEnumID], 
    [Extent2].[RequiredFlag] AS [RequiredFlag], 
    [Extent2].[ValidationRegex] AS [ValidationRegex], 
    [Extent2].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion1], 
    [Extent2].[PassengerTripStopTypeEnumID] AS [PassengerTripStopTypeEnumID], 
    [Extent2].[LastChangeSecSessionID] AS [LastChangeSecSessionID1], 
    [Extent2].[LastChangeTimeUTC] AS [LastChangeTimeUTC1], 
    [Extent4].[CustomFieldID] AS [CustomFieldID1], 
    [Extent4].[CustomFieldCode] AS [CustomFieldCode], 
    [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent4].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion2], 
    [Extent4].[LastChangeSecSessionID] AS [LastChangeSecSessionID2], 
    [Extent4].[LastChangeTimeUTC] AS [LastChangeTimeUTC2]
FROM    [dbo].[ClientCustomFieldValue] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ClientCustomField] AS [Extent2] 
    ON ([Extent2].[DeleteFlag] = 0) 
    AND ([Extent1].[ClientCustomFieldID] = [Extent2].[ClientCustomFieldID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ClientCustomField] AS [Extent3] 
    ON ([Extent3].[DeleteFlag] = 0) 
    AND ([Extent1].[ClientCustomFieldID] = [Extent3].[ClientCustomFieldID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustomField] AS [Extent4] 
    ON ([Extent4].[DeleteFlag] = 0) 
    AND ([Extent3].[CustomFieldID] = [Extent4].[CustomFieldID])
WHERE ([Extent1].[DeleteFlag] = 0) 
    AND ([Extent1].[PassengerTripID] = @p__linq__0)
',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=96
```

I would like to know why there are two left join with 'ClientCustomField' table. Kindly help me understand this.

Comment: Don't suppose you would mind showing us the Entity Framework class definitions of those 3 EF classes? A screenshot from the diagram would be great, or the code would be fine as well. I have a theory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an assumption.

First left join, denoted as `Extent2`, is for the `SELECT` clause to retrieve all necessary fields from `ClientCustomField` table. This would be presented in the query anyway, no matter if there is an `Include` method call.

Second left join, denoted as `Extent3`, is to retrieve `CustomField` table fields. As you can see it is not used anywhere except for the last left join clause that is created specifically for that as it joins everything with the `CustomField`. That is something produced by the `Include` call.

Apparently LINQ is not checking what tables where already joined in the query, and processing each of the parts of the query separately it generated two left joins for each of them.